# How to skip extra 'sign in with' page in Flask App Builder / Airflow

Tags: airflow, flask-security, flask-appbuilder

I have started using **Apache Airflow** (Built upon FAB) and enabled authentication through OAuth (as shown in [FAB Security](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-oauth)). I have ONLY one OAUTH_PROVIDER (azure).

FYI, Airflow version 2.1.4

When I launch my airflow home page, it used to open the direct login page of my OAUTH_PROVIDER.

[image: Airflow 2.1.4 Login page]

NOW, the real problem started when I upgraded my airflow to 2.2.4 AND configured the same OAUTH (Azure) provider.

When I launch my airflow home page, a page coming like this

[image: Airflow 2.2.4 Login page]

After clicking the button "Sign In with azure", the user login page comes.

Compared to the older airflow, the latest version got an extra page.

**Why is matter to me?**

We are rendering airflow in a web app and this extra "sign in with" page does not look good.

Please provide some info on SKIPPING that extra interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After upgrading Airflow, Flask Appbuilder version was probably also bumped and that caused change in behavior. Basically:

- `Flask Appbuilder < 3.4.0` made it possible to have automatic sign-in when just one oauth provider was configured
- `Flask Appbuilder >= 3.4.0` changed the behavior and made it impossible to achieve this. This is the PR (with justification) that removed this functionality: https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/pull/1707

If you want previous behavior to be used in your deployment, this is what most likely would work (although I didn't test it):

1. Prepare custom view class, let's call it `CustomAuth0AuthView` - it would bring back old behavior on `login` method. (I used v4.1.3 as reference code and modified it slightly).

`webserver_config.py`:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthOAuthView


class CustomAuthOAuthView(AuthOAuthView):
    @expose("/login/")
    @expose("/login/<provider>")
    @expose("/login/<provider>/<register>")
    def login(self, provider: Optional[str] = None) -> WerkzeugResponse:
        log.debug("Provider: {0}".format(provider))
        if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
            log.debug("Already authenticated {0}".format(g.user))
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)

        if provider is None:
            if len(self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_providers) > 1:
                return self.render_template(
                    self.login_template,
                    providers=self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_providers,
                    title=self.title,
                    appbuilder=self.appbuilder,
                )
            else:
                provider = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_providers[0]["name"]

        log.debug("Going to call authorize for: {0}".format(provider))
        state = jwt.encode(
            request.args.to_dict(flat=False),
            self.appbuilder.app.config["SECRET_KEY"],
            algorithm="HS256",
        )
        try:
            if provider == "twitter":
                return self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].authorize_redirect(
                    redirect_uri=url_for(
                        ".oauth_authorized",
                        provider=provider,
                        _external=True,
                        state=state,
                    )
                )
            else:
                return self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].authorize_redirect(
                    redirect_uri=url_for(
                        ".oauth_authorized", provider=provider, _external=True
                    ),
                    state=state.decode("ascii") if isinstance(state, bytes) else state,
                )
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Error on OAuth authorize: {0}".format(e))
            flash(as_unicode(self.invalid_login_message), "warning")
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
```

2. Prepare custom security manager. Let's call it `CustomSecurityManager`. It would use your custom view to handle login.

`webserver_config.py`:

```
from airflow.www.security import AirflowSecurityManager


class CustomSecurityManager(AirflowSecurityManager):
    authoidview = CustomAuthOAuthView
```

3. Configure Airflow to use your `CustomSecurityManager`

`webserver_config.py`:

```
SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = CustomSecurityManager
```

More on this:

- https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#your-custom-security
- https://developer.squareup.com/blog/secure-apache-airflow-using-customer-security-manager/

Comment: This is exactly what I did .. :)

Comment: In my CustomAuthOAuthView I simply called super.login() with my default provider set. Seems to work too
 ````class CustomAuthOAuthView(AuthOAuthView):
        @expose("/login/")
        @expose("/login/<provider>")
        @expose("/login/<provider>/<register>")
        def login(self, provider="twitter", register=None):
          logging.debug("Provider: {0}".format(provider))
          return super().login(provider)
````